# MySQL db returns Decimal('number') values, how to convert datatype in python?

Tags: python, mysql

Title says it all really. Making a call to a MySQL db and get a datatype that is not playing so well when I try and jsonify it. It's driving me crazy trying to convert this datatype to something useable for the front end.

I've tried calling float, int, etc, etc. Either the Decimal type persists or I get an encoding error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf4 in position 1: invalid continuation byte
```

Edit:

```
sample query result:
(('Albania', '38521', '2011'), ('Algeria', '136964', '2011'), ('Antigua and Barbuda', '206', '2011'), ('Argentina', '86351', '2011'), ('Armenia', '3251', '2011'), ('Aruba', '11511', '2011'), ('Australia', '421690', '2011'), ('Azerbaijan', '31622', '2011'),

top line of query: 
original:
SELECT s.country_area AS country, SUM(s.quantity) AS quantity, m.maxyear AS maxyear

v2:
SELECT s.country_area AS country, CAST(SUM(s.quantity) AS CHAR) AS quantity, m.maxyear AS maxyear
```

edit2:

```
v3: 
SELECT s.country_area AS country, CAST(SUM(s.quantity) AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8) AS quantity, m.maxyear AS maxyear
```

original gets Decimal error when I use json.dumps on the object
v2 get utf-8 encoding error..
v2 still get utf-8 encoding error..

Comment: What's your value? How is your table defined? Which kind of connector/ORM do you use?

Comment: im using mysql-python in a flask environment - the datatype of the original value is 'int' in the mysql data base but I'm performing a sum function over the 'quantity' column

Comment: OK, so you should get a `int`. Can you edit your question an post your Object/Table mapping (a sample).

Comment: I just need to convert the resulting sum quantity to parse to json and pass to the front-end

Answer (score -1):

The problem may be caused by accentuated characters in the *country_area* field.

If you get bytes strings from your SQL result, you must decoded it using the encoding of your table.

By default, MySQL use the latin1_swedish_ci => ISO-8859-1 charset.

So, you need to decode like this:

```
s = b"bytes string with accentuated characters"
u = s.decode("ISO-8859-1")
```

You'll get unicode characters.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to implement that in a query?

Comment: doing so in python doesn't seem to help.